# Quickbooks: Unable to connect with non Sandbox company

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am being unable to get access token for the company my account is part of. It is rather connecting with Sandbox companies only. How do I remove it? Below is screen of [oAuth Playground](https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/)

As you can see it is only showing Sandbox companies once I made a couple while exploring.

[image]

**Update**

Error while generating tokens for production key:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using your PRODUCTION OAuth consumer key and secret?

Doesn't look like it...

If you're using SANDBOX/DEVELOPMENT tokens, then you will only be able to connect to SANDBOX companies.

Comment: Development. But I am getting this screen since I created sandboxes. Also, I am only able to query Sandbox companies only not the original one as it is not generating token for them

Comment: If you're using development tokens, you can only connect to sandbox companies. Use production tokens if you want to connect to production companies.

Comment: I did get that later but oAuth playground not letting me to generate Access Token

Comment: Why are you using the OAuth playground for production keys? Click the CONNECT TO QUICKBOOKS button and go through the OAuth connection process to get your keys instead.

Comment: I logged out and Log in and refreshed. It worked then. Thanks. Since I want to use app on my own, is it possible to keep it on my own rather than sending for submission in APPStore?

Comment: **Click the CONNECT TO QUICKBOOKS** 

The script will run as a CRON JOB instead of user interaction.

Comment: Running via cron is totally irrelevant. You still need to click the CONNECT TO QUICKBOOKS button the VERY FIRST TIME YOU CONNECT. After you do it once, you never need to do it again. You can "private public" which means you don't submit to the app store but still get production tokens.

Comment: *You still need to click the CONNECT TO QUICKBOOKS button the VERY FIRST TIME YOU CONNECT. After you do it once, you never need to do it again* - Yes I have done it once and I find there is an API *Reconnect*, it's for renew tokens, correct me if I am wrong?

Also, can you please clarify *private public* thing and where can I set it? I don't want my app go for app store or get rejected.

Comment: Typo on my part - should have been "private publish". Click the PUBLISH button within your Intuit Developer account for the app. The reconnect APIs are used to renew the tokens, yes (they expire after 6 months, you can renew them after 5). This is all explained in Intuit's documentation.

Comment: In one of my apps I find this only(http://imgur.com/a/8sHJN) no Publish button as such. I assume if  I don't fill it up it will remain in private production mode

Comment: Why are you not reading the docs, or submitting a support ticket to Intuit?

Comment: Speaking as someone who's trying to do the same thing, the docs are useless.  Not even next-to-useless, but simply useless. They are almost worse than nothing.

That said, why aren't you submitting a support request to Intuit?